# Adding Integers to ArrayList until reached end of line

Tags: java, file, eol

I have a `file` filled with data. I want to add `integers` which are after `char` to `ArrayList`, and then that `ArrayList` put into the `map`. What's wrong with the reading until end of line?

My code: putting `integers` into `ArrayList` until newline was found.

Data:

```html
300 J 2 1 3
900 K 0 2
500 E 4 1
100 F 5
```

My code:

```html
while(scan.next() != "\n") {
indexes.add(scan.nextInt());
}
myMap.put(name.get(i), indexes);
```

Comment: For the last line \n will not be found so it will get stuck.

Comment: What should be expected contents of arraylist?

Comment: ArrayList: [2, 1, 3]. Then I put this ArrayList into the Map. Clear the Arraylist and add [0, 2] - putting into the Map. Clear the ArrayList and put [4, 1] and so on

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong function

`scan.next()` return:

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

You using `!=` to compare with `"\n"` is wrong. (if you want to compare, you have to use `String.equals()`. If you want to test end of file, you should use `hasNext()`

You don't need to get until end of line, `scanner.nextLine()` read the whole line for you

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
   String line = scan.nextLine();
   String[] parts = line.split(" ");
   for (String part : parts) {
     try {
       int n = Integer.parseInt(part);
       // Add to your list
       indexes.add(n);
     } catch (Exception ex) {
       // log
     }
   }
}
```